# Cannot import both numpy and LAMMPS to python after installing with conda

Tags: lammps, python, software-assistance

I installed the module LAMMPS by using this command

```
conda install -c conda-forge lammps
```

I want to import LAMMPS to python code, but it says:

```
>>> import lammps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lammps'
```

Anyone can tell me how to import lammps to python.

Comment: What is your default Python path? When you open the interpreter, what version of Python and source is listed?

Comment: The python path is in the anaconda /Users/luonghuuduc/anaconda3/. After opening the interpreter, it say: Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Is conda active, i.e. have you run 'conda activate'? If yes, your shell should show the conda environment, e.g. '(base) bash-4.2$'.

Comment: I tried it on my mac and didn't get an import error. Are you certain the install finished successfully? My conda installation is somewhat of a mess, so larger module installs will often fail unless I put them into a new virtual environment, i.e. `conda create -n lammps -c conda-forge lammps; conda activate lammps`

Comment: I run '''conda activate lammps'''. I can import lammps, but now can not numpy.

Comment: You have to reinstall all packages in the lammps environment. Run "conda activate lammps" and then "pip install numpy"

Comment: @BinhThien You also need to have numpy installed in this new environment (e.g. using `conda install -c conda-forge numpy`), is it the case ?

Comment: Did the previous comments resolve this? If so, you can write up what you did to fix it as an answer.

Comment: Also if the previous comments did *not* help, you can let us know in a comment and the question can be re-opened.